# Specify endorsing peer when Service Discovery is disabled

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have a Hyperledger-Fabric network with two organisations: Org1 and Org2.
The service discovery is disabled.

When organization 1 submits a transaction in a channel, can he designate endorsing peer of other organizations in the channel to endorse it?
How to do it? Since the service discovery is disabled, organization1 may generate peer info from the channel config block?

Answer (score 0):

It would help to say which client API and/or language you are using.

With discovery disabled, your client is only going to know about the nodes defined in the connection profile that it uses to connect to the network. For a Node client, you can use [setEndorsingOrganizations()](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/module-fabric-network.Transaction.html#setEndorsingOrganizations) or [setEndorsingPeers()](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/module-fabric-network.Transaction.html#setEndorsingPeers) on the Transaction object. For Java you can use [setEndorsingPeers()](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway-java/release-2.2/org/hyperledger/fabric/gateway/Transaction.html#setEndorsingPeers(java.util.Collection)) on the Transaction object. For Go you can use the [WithEndorsingPeers](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/gateway?utm_source=godoc#WithEndorsingPeers) option.

I would recommend configuring discovery in your network and using it in your clients. You will need to have discovery enabled to use the new [Fabric Gateway service](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.4/gateway.html) and [Fabric Gateway client API](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway/) introduced with Fabric v2.4. If you can use that, I would highly recommend it instead of the legacy SDKs.